# Missing kernel for GPU with a tf.int64 variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow and Python for implementing a simple competitive neural network.

Running epoch `k`, I need to store the index of the winner node and use it in epoch `k+1`. I am having an issue with variable types, whose solution confuses me.

Actually, I understand the main problem since I have read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439299/no-gpu-kernel-for-an-int32-variable-op), but I think I need to save that value somewhere on the GPU.

I prepared a simple example for showing what I am talking about:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    vec = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform( [3], 0.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float64), dtype=tf.float64, name='random_vector' )
    var1 = tf.arg_max(vec, 0)

    var2 = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int64, name='variable2')
    var2_op = tf.assign(var2, var1)

    sess.run(var2_op)
```

Let's say that, at the end of the epoch `k`, I have the vector `vec` and I need to store the index of the location with the maximum value, corresponding to `var1`. Before moving to epoch `k+1`, I want to store the value of `var1` in the variable `var2`.

If I run the previous code I get error:

**Cannot assign a device to node 'variable2': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.**

I can provide the full stack trace but I think it is not needed here.

So the question is: am I forced to use a `tf.float64` variable and cast the values from/to `tf.int64` every time I use it? Do you know other possible ways to solve the problem described above?

Answer (score 0):

Currently half, float, and double are supported:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/variable_ops.cc#L89

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h#L171

Might be worth filing a tensorflow github issue on this. The code is templatized, so the support of int64 variable should be straightforward. However, for arithmetic operations, GPUs' support for int64 is not as complete as that for float and double.